# What's a better way to ask this?

Tags: discussion

I posted this question:
[What was the impact of 9/11](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/469/what-was-the-impact-of-9-11)

Basically what I'm wanting is, in what ways was the United Stated impacted, or what changed, because of the attack.

Comment: That is a *very* broad question. I could probably spend the next year pasting in newspaper clippings, and not really capture the answer. I could probably also write a much, much longer critique here, if you really need it... Are you sure you don't want to be more specific?

Comment: @Shog9, I'm open to suggestions to narrow it down

Answer (score 5):

That is a *very* broad question. You could narrow it down considerably and it would *still* be a fairly broad question:

- What was the impact of the 9/11 WTC attacks *on US foreign policy*?
- What was the impact of the 9/11 WTC attacks *on the US economy*?
- What was the impact of the 9/11 WTC attacks *on US law*?
- What was the impact of the 9/11 WTC attacks *on US pop culture*?
- Etc...

You might fill a book trying to answer any one of those; trying to answer *all of them and more* in the space of a single answer seems unlikely to succeed. On top of that, the question isn't bounded by a specific time-frame either, so the implication is that anything that changed *between then and now* should be considered.

My recommendation is that you try to focus a bit on what you need to know, describe what you're researching or curious about, and let the question follow from that.